# Azure WebJobs is unavailable when Github is added to the Deployment Center

Tags: python, github, azure-web-app-service, azure-webjobs, github-actions

The idea is I want to run the Python scripts on Webjobs via Github, as all the python scripts are stored in GitHub.

I'm new to WebJob and not sure whether this is possible, because after I added GitHub to the Deployment Center, I cannot add a WebJob.

If this is possible, then how should I do this?

If this is not possible, is there any other alternative ways that can achieve the idea of running python scripts via GitHub on Azure?

Thanks in advance !
[image]

Comment: Has your problem been solved? Is there any progress?

Comment: I have tried it and it can solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

***You can disconnect git connection first, then try to add webjob package.***

Or you can deploy webjob by `Visual Studio 2019` or other `IDE`.